# React - How to avoid re-rendering children every time parent's useRef changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am passing **optionOnClick** in child components and when this **optionOnClick** fired all the child components re-rendered.

```
function ProductCriteriaGroup({criteriaGroups , calculatedCriteriaMatching, bookingId, getpotentialNumberOnCriteriaValueChange}: Props) {
    const productCriteriaServiceRef = useRef<IProductCriteriaService>(createProductCriteriaServiceByGroup(criteriaGroups, calculatedCriteriaMatching));
    const [criteriaGroupList, setCriteriaGroupList] = useState<MITCriteriaGroup[]>();

    useEffect(() => {
        productCriteriaServiceRef.current = createProductCriteriaServiceByGroup(criteriaGroups, calculatedCriteriaMatching);
        setCriteriaGroupList(convertToMITGroupList(productCriteriaServiceRef.current.getCriteriaGroupList()));
      }, [bookingId]);
    
    const optionOnClick = (criteriaId: string, mitOptions: MITOption[])=>{
        if(!productCriteriaServiceRef.current) return;
        const optionConfiguration = productCriteriaServiceRef.current.getCriteriaById(criteriaId).optionConfiguration;
        const mitOptionsMap = new Map(mitOptions.map(option => [option.optionId, option]));
        optionConfiguration.options.forEach(option => {
          const mitOption = mitOptionsMap.get(option.optionId);
          if (mitOption) {
            option.isSelected = mitOption.isSelected;
          }
        });
        optionConfiguration.handleChange();
        getpotentialNumberOnCriteriaValueChange?.(productCriteriaServiceRef.current.productCriteriaPotential);
    }


    const criteriaViewType = (criteria: MITCriteria) : ViewType => {
        ...............................
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {criteriaGroupList?.map((criteriaGroup, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                {criteriaGroup.groupName}
                ---------
                {criteriaGroup.criteriaList.map((criteria) => {
                       if (criteriaViewType(criteria) === ViewType.MultiSelect) {
                        return <MultiSelect criteria={criteria} key={criteria.criteriaId} onClick={optionOnClick} />;
                        } else {
                        return <SingleSelect criteria={criteria} key={criteria.criteriaId} onClick={optionOnClick} />
                    }
                })}
                ------------------------------------------
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductCriteriaGroup;
```

This is the code of one child component.

```
function MultiSelect({criteria, onClick}: Props) {
    const [options , setOptions] = useState<MITOption[]>(criteria.optionConfiguration ? criteria.optionConfiguration.options:[]);
    console.log(`criteria${criteria.criteriaId}`);
    const handleOptionChange = (optionId: string, checked: boolean ) =>{
        const modifiedOptions = options.map(option => option.optionId ===optionId? {...option, isSelected: checked}: option);
        setOptions(modifiedOptions);
        onClick(criteria.criteriaId, modifiedOptions);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {criteria.criteriaName}:::::MultiSelect
            {options.map((option) => (
                <div key={option.optionId}>
                <input
                type="checkbox"
                name={criteria.criteriaId} // Use the criteria ID as the name
                value={option.optionId}
                checked={option.isSelected} // Set the checked state based on isSelected
                onChange={(e) => handleOptionChange(option.optionId, e.target.checked)}
                />
                {option.optionsName}
            </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      );
    }

export default MultiSelect;
```

The ProductCriteriaGroup is called from BookingDetails.

```
function BookingDetails() {
const bookingId = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
const { booking , calculatedCriteriaMatching, potentialCriteriaCount, setPotentialCriteriaCount } = useBookingInfo(bookingId);
const criteriaGroups = booking?.productCriteriaInformations || [];

const getPotentialNumberOnCriteriaValueChange = useCallback((count: number) => {
    setPotentialCriteriaCount(count);
  }, []); 


if(calculatedCriteriaMatching === undefined || criteriaGroups.length === 0) return (<div>Loading..</div>);
return (
    <div>
        PotentialCriteriaCount : {potentialCriteriaCount}
       <ProductCriteriaGroup criteriaGroups={criteriaGroups} 
                            calculatedCriteriaMatching={calculatedCriteriaMatching}
                            bookingId={bookingId} 
                            getpotentialNumberOnCriteriaValueChange={getPotentialNumberOnCriteriaValueChange}/>
    </div>
);
```

}

export default BookingDetails;

How to avoid re-rendering all child components?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right. Do you mean the components are re-rendering when `optionClick` is fired but do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Yes all the child component is not dependent on productCriteriaServiceRef. So I don't want re render child components

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are directly mutating the child objects via the `optionOnClick` function. This is causing them to all re-render as every time you run this function, new versions of the child objects are created.

The solution is to use the `useCallback` hook and memoize the transaction, such as follows:

```js
const optionOnClick = useCallback((criteriaId: string, mitOptions: MITOption[])=>{
    if(!productCriteriaServiceRef.current) return;
    const optionConfiguration = productCriteriaServiceRef.current.getCriteriaById(criteriaId).optionConfiguration;
    const mitOptionsMap = new Map(mitOptions.map(option => [option.optionId, option]));

    ~~optionConfiguration.options.forEach(option => {~~
    ~~    const mitOption = mitOptionsMap.get(option.optionId);~~
    ~~    if (mitOption) {~~
    ~~        option.isSelected = mitOption.isSelected;~~
    ~~    }~~
    ~~});~~
    const updatedOptions = optionConfiguration.options.map(option => {
        const mitOption = mitOptionsMap.get(option.optionId);
        return mitOption ? { ...option, isSelected: mitOption.isSelected } : option;
    });

    optionConfiguration.options = updatedOptions;
    optionConfiguration.handleChange();
    getpotentialNumberOnCriteriaValueChange?.(productCriteriaServiceRef.current.productCriteriaPotential);
}, [getpotentialNumberOnCriteriaValueChange]);
```

I've used strike-through MD syntax to indicate the changes. In this version, we create a new object called updatedOptions via map. We then update the state with this new object. We've also wrapped the function in `useCallback` hook. This will prevent the function from being created anew each iteration of the components rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found the problem. When optionOnClick  is called, I change the one useState of BookingDetails component. For this reason, it renders all the child and grandchild components. I have to React.memo and useCallback for fixing this issue.